# How to use RecyclerView like GridView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My DB is like this.

[image]

I will show you DATA when I search my name on SearchView.

This is the layout of the Adapter.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Data No."
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

One nameText and one dataText.

If I search for JOHN1, I wish he would appear like this.

Like GridView.

```
JOHN1 JOHN1 JOHN1 JOHN1
10    20    30    40
```

But I don't know what to do with Adapter's onBindViewHolder.

It's Adapter.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

    List<Data> dataList;
    Context context;

    public Adapter(List<Data> dataList, Context context) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
//        holder.nameText.setText(dataList.get(position).getName());
//        holder.dataText.setText(dataList.get(position).getData1());
//        holder.dataText.setText(dataList.get(position).getData2());
//        holder.dataText.setText(dataList.get(position).getData3());
//        holder.dataText.setText(dataList.get(position).getData4());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView nameText, dataText;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
            dataText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dataText);
        }
    }
}
```

Plz help me...

Comment: https://github.com/monsterbrain/RecyclerviewTableViewAndroid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Multi Type holders

good sample is here:
[sample](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-multiple-view-holder-af798458763b)

Comment: you can use Multi Type holders

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand.
There's only one POJO and I use getItemViewType?

Comment: yes, for strings use some holder like `NameHolder`, and for `int` values use some Holder like `AgeHolder`

Comment: Is it okay if it's all String value?

Comment: no, you can use for all data type, lock at the sample , that is really useful

Comment: I didn't know the link changed. Thank you very much. How useful!

Answer (score 1):

The table like structure is a very old pattern and is not accepted as per the design guidelines. Suggestion is to use a single card with multiple `textviews` whose data can be set using the `viewHolder` in `onBindViewHolder` method.

Check this link for [Cards](https://material.io/components/cards)

Check this link for [how to create a card-based layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview)

You can use a `Staggered` or a `Grid` `Layout Manager` for your `RecyclerView` which would give you a good look for showing the data.

You can check both styles in [this article](https://medium.com/@kamalvaid/recyclerview-orientation-types-9d15c3424d85)

Now if all this does not convince you and you want to stick to the design that you mentioned, then you can have a `ViewHolder` with `LinearLayout` and `horizontal` orientation in which you can `add` the `view` with `title` and `description` dynamically by looping over the object and setting the `title` and `description` values. **Title would be repetitive in this case and use unnecessary space on the screen as per the design.** So it is not recommended to go with this design.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To use `RecyclerView` like `GridView`:

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), NUMBER_OF_COLUMN));
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

But in your case, I saw your `database` is stored like 1 object `response` contains `name`, `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, `data4` fields.

```
{
   "response":{
      "name":"John",
      "data1":10,
      "data2":20,
      "data3":30,
      "data4":40
   }
}
```

If you want display as

```
JOHN1 JOHN1 JOHN1 JOHN1
10    20    30    40
```

**DONT** use `Gridlayout`. `Gridlayout` should be use in case your data is like

```
{
   "response":[
      {
         "name":"John",
         "data":10
      },
      {
         "name":"John",
         "data":20
      },
      {
         "name":"John",
         "data":30
      },
      {
         "name":"John",
         "data":40
      }
   ]
}
```

Of course you can convert your object `response` to array object like below json, but it isn't necessary. Just use `RecyclerView` as normal is better idea